# Should I close the FileInputStream multiple times if reinstantiate it

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

Following is the code. I am doing it right by calling close only once?

```
public class SeatTest extends TestCase {
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    ArrayList<File> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        File dir = new File("./data/test/seat_layouts");
        fileNames = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testParse() throws IOException {
        for (File file : fileNames) {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            String everyThing = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            //do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Defiantly you should close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I close the FileInputStream multiple times if reinstantiate it.

Yes .... sort of.

Each instance of `FileInputStream` should be closed or you risk leaking file descriptors.  Each time you "reinstantiate" the object, you are creating a new instance, and each instance should be closed.

For example

```
@Test
public void testParse() throws IOException {
    for (File file : fileNames) {
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            String everyThing = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `try-with-resource` will close the resource (i.e. `inputStream`) automatically.

If you do it this way, the teardown code is not required.